# Some way to access Facebook page data with PHP or JS

Tags: php, facebook

I have a Facebook page feed that I want to access:

```
http://facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=123456789 (Not a real ID)
```

When I put the URL in the browser, it works just fine, but when I try to access it using file_get_contents, Facebook sends me to a page that says I am using an unsupported browser. This data is public though so I shouldn't need an access token to obtain it. Is there an extra step I need to take in order to access this data? I also tried using cURL with no success.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use curl and mimic a browser, [see this thread](http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=256757.0) on how to do it.

```
$header = array();
$header[] = 'Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5';
$header[] = 'Cache-Control: max-age=0';
$header[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$header[] = 'Keep-Alive: 300';
$header[] = 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7';
$header[] = 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5';
$header[] = 'Pragma: ';
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'YOUR URL HERE');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.11) Gecko/2009060215 Firefox/3.0.11 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: @jasonaburton: Do you have curl extension turned on from php.ini ?

Comment: Well what do you know. I took the code you pasted here and just inserted my URL and it works. I must have been doing something wrong. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use this url, it is really really old method to access it. Use their relatively new [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using the API altogether.

Comment: What you were using is an API, too.

Comment: Well, I was hoping to not have to go through the process of creating an app and gaining an access token and etc etc. I just want to pull some info from a feed.

Comment: You won't be able to do that until you're sending cookies from logged in user

Comment: @jasonaburton You have to do that once, and it takes like 15 seconds. C'mon.