# get website correct source with php curl

Tags: php, facebook, curl, web-crawler

I've written a simple PHP script to fetch websites' source with CURL :

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__)."/curl/cacert.pem");

$data = curl_exec($ch);
$url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if($data === false)
    return false;
return array("content" => $data, "url" => $url, "httpcode" => $httpcode);
}

$data = file_get_contents_curl("https://www.facebook.com");

print_r($data);
```

In this example , I'm fetching facebook source, but it gets the page which is related to unsupported browsers. In fact the final URL after redirecting is this : **http://www.facebook.com/unsupportedbrowser**

what's the problem?

Comment: Facebook does not mean *your* browser. It means **curl**.

Comment: you realize that it's **CURL** doing this request, not your browser? facebook does browser detection/redirection, and it doesn't recognize curl.

Comment: why vote down ? Just because I mentioned my browser? Please tell me the solution not voting down...

Comment: You will have to set user-agent with cURL to make Facebook think that cURL is a browser.

Comment: if you really want to do something with Facebook, you shouldn't use CURL but check out the official developer documentation instead https://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: @Ali: You see downvotes because that can happen if you don't do your homework. Only because something does not work, it must not mean you need to post a question on stackoverflow. The "what's the problem" here should be best answered: You are seeing a message you don't understand.

Comment: It's not only the problem with facebook. it's just an example. many sites make this problem when fetching data with CURL

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239367/get-html-source-of-a-https-page-by-forcing-a-user-agent-in-ruby  - Please search first for your problem.

Comment: @hakre - This isn't really a duplicate of that question, firstly that question is in Ruby, and secondly, they **were** setting the user-agent, but as `User Agent` instead of `User-Agent`.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff: Yes, because you need a bit-by-bit copy for having a duplicate? Sorry but OP didn't obviously not look for the error message first. I could google that quickly. This is more a google request than a question in my eyes.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is a Q and A site, right? Just because this is a trivial question to you does not mean it's a bad question.

Comment: @hakre Also, although there is the same end result in both questions, people searching for something like `php curl facebook unsupported browser chrome` won't find a question/answer about Ruby :-)

Comment: @Shaquin Trifonoff : I'm still sad of the down votes! I think it was not my right... :((

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff: Well, if you leave the chrome out, you get this as first hit on google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587752/some-way-to-access-facebook-page-data-with-php-or-js - So if that is not sad, I don't know. Maybe that is your bit-by-bit duplicate now? **Edit:** you don't have to leave the chrome out, just see the first google result for your exact search query.

Comment: @relentless: If running a google search is not needed before asking a question, you should become comfortable with getting the site swamped. Probably you expect from a Q and A community that others are cleaning behind your back?

Comment: @hakre Oh well... Ali, did you search for your problem before asking? If so, which search terms?

Comment: @hakre - I don't disagree that one should do research before posting. However, in certain cases such as this, the OP might not have a clue what to ask/how to ask. Now, if he hadn't of posted his attempt and goal I'd agree 100% that it was a bad question, should be downvoted and closed.

Comment: @hakre - and what does this mean, "that others are cleaning behind your back?"

Comment: @relentless - It means close votes, delete votes, and down-votes.

Comment: @Shaquin Trifonoff : I searched `php get website source curl unsupported browser`, I think...

Comment: @ali The first result for that search is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10587805), why couldn't you use that?

Comment: @Shaquin Trifonoff : in google search , this is result number 8 , although different IPs from different regions might differ in results ranking...

Comment: @ali Yes, search results do differ. Google puts what it thinks are more relevant results at the top. At least now, other people searching for the same problem are more likely to find the solution :-)

Comment: @Shaquin Trifonoff : I don't think so ! because of the down votes , they think it's a fake and irrelevant question , so exit the page quickly :))

Comment: @ali Unfortunately, that might happen, especially since it has now been closed as 'not a real question'. :-/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to set the user-agent with cURL so that Facebook recognizes it, like this:

```
$ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) \ 
Chrome/24.0.1304.0 Safari/537.16'
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
```

Comment: You can set the user-agent (`$ua`) to any modern browser's user-agent, the one in this code is just an example (from my browser).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Users who answer questions must be appreciated , not down voters and complainers...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is cURL.

Even if you run your script via browser, a cURL request is made from the server, it means the request being made to the target site is raw, without any client information.

I suggest you googling for some information on how to make your curl pretend a human, but actually you should start with sending a CORRECT User-Agent header information, along with your request.